# Tumblr HTML : how to show photo caption upon hover / rollover?

Tags: html, hover, tumblr, rollover, caption

Brand new to this. Apologies in advance if this is extremely elementary...

I am using a photo grid theme that doesn't show the caption until you click through.

However, i would love to reveal the caption if the user rolls over or hovers over the photo.

Here is the site:

http://haiku-movie-review.tumblr.com/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the code that reveals the caption on click?

Comment: You should show an attempt, SO helps you fix the problem, not solve the whole problem...

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to add `title="What you want to display"` to the images. You can see that in effect at http://xkcd.com by rolling over the picture in the middle of the screen.